# Confused about git submodule and .git folders

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I had my project set up like this

LocalParentProject ---------------> mygithub/LocalParentProject

/SubmoduleProject ---------------> mygithub/SubmoduleProject

VsCode showed me both projects in Source Control when I opened the parent folder, or just the Submodule when I opened the child folder.

But then I realized that commits were different for the Submodule from its folder, or from the parent folder.

So what is the correct workflow for this, did I create my Submodule correctly?
Should I just work from the Submodule folder OR from the parent folder?

Sorry for the messy explanation ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : from both.

Well : you probably want to open the parent repo in VSCode, and just clarify what commit is stored in what place.

---

The submodule *is* a clone of a repo, with its ".git" directory stored in `.git/modules/module_name`.

If in a terminal you `cd` into the submodule's folder, you will see that `git status`, `git log`, `git fetch` ... affect the submodule, not the parent repo.

To update the submodule, you need to :

- run the actions you want within the submodule (`git pull`, or `git fetch` and `git checkout`, or ... )
- in the parent repo, run

```
git add module_name
git commit
```